# PopUpView or AlertDialog, with ImageButton matrix

Tags: android

I need to create a dialog that contains a matrix of simple square ImageButtons (like icons), in unknown number, and a Cancel button. The dialog should be inflatable programmatically and scrollable.

I really am confused: should I create a custom layout and apply it to AlertDialog? And how could I intercept the clicks? Should I use PopUpWiew? Should I make it as Activity or not?

And if I create a new Activity... should I use a Runnable?
Please don't provide me a complete source, I just need to understand what is the correct direction to go for this need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Dialog and set your layout file to it. A dialog is something like a mini activity which can be called onto an actual activity and dismissed at will.

Let this be the custom layout file - customLayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".AutoMode" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_gradient"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/red_gradient" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_gradient"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/metallic_gradient"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/purple_gradient"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"/>

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_gradient"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_gradient"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/violet_gradient"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's how you can set this layout to a dialog box in the activity where you want to call it:

```
final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(this);
    customDialog.setTitle("Matrix");
    disclaimer.setContentView(R.layout.customLayout);
      Button b1 = (Button) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do whatever you want when button1 is clicked
        }
    });
.
.//same for other buttons
.
Button b9 = (Button) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.button9)
b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do whatever you want when button9 is clicked
        }
    });
    Button close = (Button) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    customDialog.show();
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            disclaimer.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, stupidly I forgot this solution. In the meantime I was exploring the GridView in order to obtain the same thing, now I'll check which solution is the most appropriate, thanks anyway.